# CSM boot with Win7 and Ubuntu Toshiba

Tags: dual-boot, toshiba, csm

I have a Toshiba Ultrabook with win 7 installed.

I would like to dual boot with Linux.

In the bios, the disk is set to CSM mode. In CSM mode, I don't have an option to boot from USB.

If I set the bios to UEFI, I can boot from USB. If I try install Ubuntu, it does not see windows.

In UEFI mode, it also won't boot to Windows.

As much I as I have read, I cant see a way around this.

I have the WIN7 on an image with Reflect so maybe I change the BIOS to UEFI and restore the image ?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You gave no Ubuntu product/release details of what you're trying to install, but I'm involved with Ubuntu Q&A with desktops & can tell you Ubuntu will install in legacy/BIOS, uEFI or Secure-uEFI if the ISO is written to media correctly (*as is documented*) without change (*some ISO writers allow reformats of ISO which can prevent this!*), but Windows & Ubuntu should be installed in the same mode. Booting external media however is device specific; ie. that's a question related to your brand/model of hardware & not related to the OS (Ubuntu in this case outside of using *non-revoked* keys).